# -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
// Configure the cell.
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.drinks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];
return cell;
```

The above code is generating this exception. What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: That error is saying it thinks `[self.drinks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` is a string object as opposed to a dictionary.  Without seeing the rest of the code I can't see if that's the case, or if this is more involved, but you may want to check that.

Comment: after this line...my code is getting stopped n my app is paused....wtz this?...m fresher on iphone as well as stackoverflow also...so wt should i do?

Comment: I would suggest checking what objects are in your array, MaKo has suggested a way to do this.

Comment: itz working fine when i use " cell.textLabel.text = [self.drinks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    but when i add ObjectForKey:@"name"; it stops my app.

Comment: Ok, good, it is intact a string, therefore the objectForKey: call is not needed as that is meant to get an object out of a dictionary based on the given key.

Comment: @khushbushah When writing a question or response, use complete English words. "n", "m", "wt", and "wtz" are just painful to read and will make people less likely to want to help you.

Comment: oh k....actually i am new for this...next time i will take care...thanks

Comment: @RyanCrews-hey,I have made one silly mistake...The nibname was wrong..now its working well.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first try to determine what object is self.drinks,

then you can go finer depending if is an array with dictionaries?

do a log

> [self.drinks objectAtIndex:0]

what do you see?

Comment: itz giving me the list of items of plist..but i want to refer particular row....for details view...so what should i do?right now m refering book"head first iphone development"

Comment: hi, I edited the answer, so you just read one place of the array, post the log so we can figure out if you have an array of dictionaries or array of arrays??, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

My Understand from Your question

You have array of drinks like

```
Drink *d1 = [[Drink alloc] init]
d1.name = @"Drink1";
d1.price = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:25.0];

Drink *d2 = [[Drink alloc] init]
d2.name = @"Drink2";
d2.price = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:35.0];
```

OR

```
NSArray *values1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Drink1",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:25.0], nil];
    NSArray *keys1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name",@"price", nil];
    NSDictionary *d1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:values1 forKeys:keys1];

    NSArray *values2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Drink2",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:55.0], nil];
    NSArray *keys2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name",@"price", nil];
    NSDictionary *d2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:values1 forKeys:keys1];


self.drinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:d1,d2, nil];
[d1 release];
[d2 release];
```

From the above case

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.drinks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];
```

the above statement is correct

You are getting exception means, You are inserting the objects into drinks array, that supports Key Value Pairs data and that is String Data.

I hope you are having like this

```
self.drinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Drink1",@"Drink2", nil];
```

In this above case you have to go with

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.drinks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```